# Regex split using a character and replace the first part with a different string

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have list of strings as follows:

```
Austria: ac.at
Bangladesh: ac.bd
Belgium: ac.be
China: ac.cn
Cyprus: ac.cy
India: ac.in
```

And I need to get a list as follows:

```
$Resolved URL$ LIKE "*ac.at/*"
$Resolved URL$ LIKE "*ac.bd/*"
$Resolved URL$ LIKE "*ac.be/*"
$Resolved URL$ LIKE "*ac.cn/*"
$Resolved URL$ LIKE "*ac.cy/*"
$Resolved URL$ LIKE "*ac.id/*"
```

What is the best way to do this using regex replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^.*?(\S+)$
Replace: $Resolved URL$ LIKE "*$1/*"
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
^          from the start of the string
    .*?    consume (but do not capture) all content
    (\S+)  up until the final collection of non word characters and capture them
$          end of the input
```

Comment: I tried that, but it keep the Country name. I need to get rid of the country names as well. thanks.

Comment: _What_ did you try?  In the demo link, my answer is completely working.

Comment: nope. I tried the Demo link. It shows the country names in the substituted text.

Answer (score 1):

Just match the five characters you wish to keep and build the replacement string around that. You can use following the regular expression.

```
[a-z]{2}\.[a-z]{2}
```

The replacement string is

```
$Resolved URL$ LIKE "*$0/*"
```

where `$0` is the string that was matched (e.g., `"ac.at"`).

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/NT8Ak7/2/)